# How to iterate Map in grails view(gsp)?

Tags: grails

I am passing the values from my controller to view and the values in map are:

```
    [title:[Feedback, Feedback, Suspension, Suspension],
     description:[Warning Letter, Warning Letter, Suspended, Suspended], 
     remark:[Testing, Testing Purpose, Bikrame, Nothing Serious], 
     date:[2015-08-12 00:00:00.0, 2015-08-19 00:00:00.0, 2015-08-22 00:00:00.0, 2015-08-25 00:00:00.0], 
     semesterNo:[2, 2, 2, 3]]
```

As i was trying to access the map using the keys in gsp

```
    <g:each in="${awardsList}" var="values" status="i">
            ${values.getAt("title")}
    </g:each>
```

I got an error as

```
No such property: title for class: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry.Stacktrace follows:
Message: Error evaluating expression [values.getAt("title")] on line [91]:
No such property: title for class: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *values* in your *g:each* block are an instance of [Map.Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html), rather than *Map*. It looks like your trying to iterate through a list of *Map*s but instead your interating through a **single** *Map*.

You can fix this by putting your controller return value in a list:

```
[
  [title:[Feedback, Feedback, Suspension, Suspension],
     description:[Warning Letter, Warning Letter, Suspended, Suspended], 
     remark:[Testing, Testing Purpose, Bikrame, Nothing Serious], 
     date:[2015-08-12 00:00:00.0, 2015-08-19 00:00:00.0, 2015-08-22 00:00:00.0, 2015-08-25 00:00:00.0], 
     semesterNo:[2, 2, 2, 3]]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Life might be simpler if your controller returned an array of maps as your awardsList:

```
[[title:'Feedback', description:'Warning Letter', remark:'Testing', date:'2015-08-12 00:00:00.0',semesterNo:2],
 [title:'Feedback',description:'Warning Letter', remark:'Testing Purpose', date:'2015-08-19 00:00:00.0', semesterNo:2],
 [title:'Suspension',description:'Suspended', remark:'Bikrame', date:'2015-08-22 00:00:00.0', semesterNo:2],
 [title:'Suspension',description:'Suspended', remark:'Nothing Serious',date:'2015-08-25 00:00:00.0',semesterNo:3]
]
```

Then:

```
<g:each in="${awardsList}" var="award">
    ${award.title}
</g:each>
```